# glob expansion not working even with shopt -s extglob set

Tags: bash

I am trying to `chmod -R 644 /tmp/work/*` in bash script, however I get following error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s extglob
set -eu

mkdir -p /tmp/work/
chmod -R 777 /tmp/work/
sftp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new user1@hostname1:/tmp/test* /tmp/work/
chmod -R 644 /tmp/work/*

chmod: cannot access '/tmp/work/*': No such file or directory
```

While I try to run the same command in shell with the same user, it runs successfully.

Seems like issue with shell is due to glob expansion? so I have set `shopt -s extglob` right before the `chmod` command in bash, but still getting the same error.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `test` in `user1@hostname1:test` a file or a directory?  The glob is just fine, and doesn't require an `extglob` at all ... I'm wondering whether the transfer actually worked ...

Comment: You are probably thinking about `nullglob` not `extglob`, but then chmod will complain about getting no files

Comment: My bad, updated the typo test is actually multiple files and the transfer completed succesfuly as i can manually login view files and even do chmod, the only issue same doest work in bash

Comment: After the `sftp` command, what does `ls /tmp/work` give you? Based on the error message, I'm expecting nothing at all